# Как перенаправить файл file.php на папку /file в правилах rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, веб-сервер, mod-rewrite

Мне нужно чтобы с ссылки вида  http://example.com/papka/file.php перенаправляло на http://example.com/papka/file
Сейчас использую такие правила, убираю .php и перенаправляю с .php, но на файлы в папке не действует.

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} " (/[^?/]+)\.php"
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```